# Kotlin: generate a Comparable#compareTo() function from the properties of a class

Tags: kotlin, compare, comparator, compareto

In Kotlin, is there any concise way to generate a `Comparable#compareTo()` function for an interface that just calls `this.property1.compareTo(that.property1)` for each property of the interface in declaration order? Obviously, every property of the interface implements `Comparable`.

For interface `I`, it looks like I can create a top-level val like:

```
private val COMPARATOR = compareBy<I>(
    {it.property1},
    {it.property2},
    {it.property3},
    ...
)
```

And `return COMPARATOR.compare(this, other)` from `I#compareTo(I)`, but, is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: I strongly recommend doing exactly what you've said above, to increase explicitness over magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection and some simple language features like so:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> compareByAll(): Comparator<T> {
    val selector = T::class.memberProperties
        .map { { i: T -> it.get(i) as Comparable<*> } }
        .toTypedArray()
    return compareBy(*selector)
}
```

Used like this:

```
val testInput = listOf(I(1, 2, 3), I(1, 2, 4), I(1, 0, 4), I(2, 3, 4), I(0, 1, 2)
testInput.sortedWith(compareByAll()))
```

Note that this solution doesn't handle the case that a property is not `Comparable`.

Comment: `T::class.memberProperties` seems to return the properties sorted alphabetically.  I want them in declaration order so I can easily control the property comparison order, as that affects the return value.  Also, is there any way to limit the iterated properties to those in the primary constructor, not all properties of the class? (I know my question didn't ask the latter part, but I just thought of some derived properties that I'd like to add that aren't necessary for comparisons)